# How to Show the Related Content in another Div when an Image Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div area (for main slider. But there will not be sliding inside).
And under this div area there is a tab system.

In these tabs there are 1-6 images (In each tab there are another images (1 to 6 images)

When I click one of these images I want to show the related content / photo etc in this Div area above.

How can I do that? Any example? Any clue?

I tried to use jquery for show/hide, toggle etc but for example I couldnt find how to keep those big divs unvisible within my html (I tried css "display:none;" but that didn't seem to me wise enough) and call them in its place (above of the tab system)

P.S: when an image is shown the others must be hidden.

Comment: Do you have any code examples? Links? A JS Fiddle? I would recommend ripping out the necessary parts and create one so we can assist with your specific problem http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Sorry Tim I haven't seen your message till now. As I said below an example is ford.ca ; Ford for Canada.

Comment: right i could rip it from ford.ca or i could code it from scratch for you or i could assist you with your code. I am not trying to be rude but the point of stackoverflow is to not have your work done for you but to assist you in an obstacle within your code. Once you have a jumping off point I would be more than happy to step in and assist. Thanks.

Comment: I understand your point Tim. But I didnt referred it because you can rip it out or you can write it by scratch for me. You asked an example. The point is I didnt even know on which effect should I take my way. I can say "no" to my friends "I cannot do this" or I can offer them to hire a js jquery expert friend. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it's this kind of thing  http://jsfiddle.net/S4LGr/  ;) I did and now feel myself so close to the exact answer

Comment: now we are getting somewhere! lol

Comment: Do you want to go on helping me? If yes, my question is : when I chenge the effect to fadeIn or fadeOut it brings my CONTENTs from background of my little images. Not within the frontiers of the big div above. It just works when I use slideDown / slideUp effect or show / hide with slow speed. Not fast. Why ? And how can I solve this? How can I use fadeIn / fadeOut ?

Comment: updating moving comment thread to my posted jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are demyr obviously you will have to modify to your exact needs:

http://jsfiddle.net/S4LGr/1/

It is no problem here is the updated code, edit as you need you should really be able to take it from here:

http://jsfiddle.net/S4LGr/3/

I changed the images on this one so you can actuall see it happen, very similiar to ford.ca:

http://jsfiddle.net/S4LGr/5/

Here you go man all the pieces brought together:

http://jsfiddle.net/S4LGr/9/

### totallyFeelLikeIdidYourHomeWork lol you owe me a beer!

Comment: But the point is, I am going to bring another big images (plus html) into this big div, not the little ones.. So annoying?

Comment: ok so can you update the fiddle with the images you are going to use? If your annoyed with my help or your lack of understanding of jQuery I will gladly step away...

Comment: No I'm not the annoyed one. I thought you might get annoyed because of my lack of Jquery understanding or my need about this Jquery app. Anyway, I have updated with new bigger images, and got the width to 350px for the big div, hope it helps.

Comment: You're exactly doing cool work. But it seems like I forgot to write you the js fiddle url (It was http://jsfiddle.net/S4LGr/2/ ). I had updated with the new images. I can hear you said 'oh god'.

Comment: same images in that fiddle bro

Comment: The point here it shows up same images with the tuhumbnails. In my example, I click on tiny image and see above a div containing html + big image. This big image is a different image. Not the same with the thumbnail. I mean, http://jsfiddle.net/S4LGr/6/  But it doesnt seem so clear, my effects.. as I wrote above

Comment: Great! Really great and can buy you a beer =) But there is another little problem. As my images in div=link, the little ones, are in "li" tag. So the jquery doesnt work at all. I updated all my html and css there. http://jsfiddle.net/S4LGr/10/  So Can you figure out jquery codes according to that? I tried all tags (ul - li) instead of "div" and "a" but couldnt succeed.

Answer (score 0):

you can bind a function on all images/text that loads the relevant images/text to the detail div. Like this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9jc46/

Comment: Can binding help me? Ok then, How to keep my big divs with all information there? Should I call them from another file? Because 6 images mean 6 big div contents. And in 4 tabs, it means 24 slider-like content.

Comment: we may need a link to your solution if possible..... my example assumes that you have some kind of examples/thumbnails/teaser text in areas of the tabs....using the function we copy that to the detail. You can then hide/show what is relevant using css. See the update http://jsfiddle.net/9jc46/1/  ....but i'm just blabbering on without an example of your problem..

Comment: Yes you got me right. I have tumbnails in my tabs. But no,I dont copy the image to the big div. There will be related content.

An example? ford.ca Ford for Canada. It's same. 

I have tried your jsfiddle but couldnt make it work for me. I mean I almost copied your lines but when I click on my little images I couldnt see any content in big div above.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/S4LGr/  Here what I did. Had some clue on another forum and completed this.